# How to calculate new box dimensions given a reduction in volume

Tags: volume, packing-problem

I have a rectangular box with given dimensions $l, w, h$ with available volume $v = lwh$. If I can only pack up to 80% of $v$, how would I go about determining the new, smaller dimensions such that the new $v = lwh$ is 80% of original $v$ where the new dimensions should be reduced proportionally to retain the original box shape?

I'm trying to write some C# code to do some bin packing testing, but this algorithm doesn't consider a box volume threshold, it only packs according to dimensions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know that $v = lwh$, so you want to determine new dimensions for which $v' = 0.8v$.  So you could reduce any *one* of the three dimensions, such as $w' = 0.8w$, to do that.  If you want to shrink the box but keep the proportions, just distribute the factor:

$$v' = 0.8v = 0.8lwh = \sqrt[3]{0.8}l\sqrt[3]{0.8}w\sqrt[3]{0.8}h$$
$$l' = \sqrt[3]{0.8}l$$
$$w' = \sqrt[3]{0.8}w$$
$$h' = \sqrt[3]{0.8}h$$

In other words, just shrink each dimension by $\sqrt[3]{80\%}$ or multiply each dimension by $\approx 0.9283$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the new length $l'=kl$, new width $w'=kw$ and new height $h'=kh$ where $k$ is the ratio of new dimensions to old dimensions. We have $l'w'h'=k^3lwh=0.8lwh$, thus $k=0.8^{1/3}$.